# Mail in Mountain Lion does not search mail server

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

Ever since upgrading to Mountain Lion, I don't get the full search results when searching my Mail. Mail is now coming back with only 2-3 months worth of search and I'm not sure those are complete. I've tried highlighting old messages, changing the order, etc. Other people are [experiencing this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4188593?start=0&tstart=0) too. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I noticed this too and my only solution is to get angry and frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with search and deleting the Spotlight index and reindexing helped.

In a Terminal:

```
sudo mdutil -i off /
sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight*
sudo mdutil -i on /
sudo mdutil -E /
```

This will trigger a reindexing, which can take a few hours.

Comment: and this will fix the MAIL search??